# The method handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList) is undefined for the type Context

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I'm trying to change my GMapV2Direction that is in `fragmentActivity` to fragment. Everything works except the method `handleGetDirectionsResult(Arraylist)`, which is undefined for the type context. I really need to change it to fragment but on searching it seems someone said that I can't do it in fragment?

This my adapter code:

```
public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<LatLng>>
 {
 public static final String USER_CURRENT_LAT = "user_current_lat";
 public static final String USER_CURRENT_LONG = "user_current_long";
 public static final String DESTINATION_LAT = "destination_lat";
 public static final String DESTINATION_LONG = "destination_long";
 public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
 private Context context;
 private Exception exception;
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(Context context)
 {
    this.context = context;
 }

public void onPreExecute()
 {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating directions");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList result)
 {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if (exception == null)
     {
        context.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
     }
    else
     {
        processException();
     }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params)
{
    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try
    {
        LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LONG)));
        LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LONG)));
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE));
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
        return directionPoints;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException()
 {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error retriving data", 3000).show();
 }
}
```

And this is my fragment:

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {

private static final LatLng AMSTERDAM = new LatLng(2.095892, 102.507584);
private static final LatLng PARIS = new LatLng(2.190484, 102.253525);

private GoogleMap map;
private SupportMapFragment fragment;
private LatLngBounds latlngBounds;
private Button bNavigation;
private Polyline newPolyline;
private boolean isTravelingToParis = false;
private boolean marker1 = false;
private int width, height;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation, container, false);

    getSreenDimanstions();
    fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = fragment.getMap();    
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    bNavigation = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bNavigation);
    bNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
                double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
                double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();     


                LatLng FRANKFURT = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
                 Marker mkrFRANKFURT = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(FRANKFURT)
                 .title("You are Here")
                    .snippet("Aloha!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

                 Marker mkr2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(AMSTERDAM)
                 .title("This is AMSTERDAM")
                    .snippet("Aloha!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

                latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, FRANKFURT);
                findDirections( AMSTERDAM.latitude, AMSTERDAM.longitude, dLatitude, dLongitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );  
                isTravelingToParis = true;
    }});

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

     Marker mkr2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(AMSTERDAM)
     .title("This is AMSTERDAM")
        .snippet("Aloha!")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(2.095892, 102.507584) , 14.0f) );

}

public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
    {          
        rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
    }
    if (newPolyline != null)
    {
        newPolyline.remove();
    }
    newPolyline = map.addPolyline(rectLine);
    if (isTravelingToParis)
    {
        Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng FRANKFURT = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, FRANKFURT);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));

    }
    else
    {
        Location myLocation  = map.getMyLocation();
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng FRANKFURT = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, FRANKFURT);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
    }
}

private void getSreenDimanstions()
{
    Display display = this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth(); 
    height = display.getHeight(); 
}

private LatLngBounds createLatLngBoundsObject(LatLng firstLocation, LatLng secondLocation)
{
    if (firstLocation != null && secondLocation != null)
    {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();    
        builder.include(firstLocation).include(secondLocation);

        return builder.build();
    }
    return null;
}

public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this.getActivity());
    asyncTask.execute(map); 
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your class GetDirectionsAsyncTask change 
   `private Context context;` to `private Activity activity;`

then, when you use

```
if(exception == null){
    context.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
```

}

you have to cast the Activity to NavigationFragment like that:

`if(exception == null){
        ((NavigationFragment)activity).handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
   }`

**Why? Because not all activities have got the method handleGetDirectionsResult(result); only NavigationFragment**

Comment: activity will not be an instance of NavigationFragment, so the cast will not work here.